# How make auto responder for specific requests

Tags: macos, apache-flex, browser, proxy, response

I need in autoresponder. I develop flash application and I need substitution flash file from server to my local debug flash.

I used Charles Proxy but in last week it became badly: internet connection very slow, some responses can't wait for request.

Is there a same solution for this micro task? May be little extension for browser? Or can anybody create this extension for chrome or safari?

Or Do you know why my Charles works slowly?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I need in tool help me replace flash on page for my local debug flash file. I used Charles but at last week it became very slow. Make sense now? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you couldn't replace your real service class with a mock.